# How should I connect new thermostat wires to my heat pump?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, heat-pump, compressor, blower

I need some direction on troubleshooting my HVAC heat pump. I have recently purchased an older home with a newer heat pump was installed. There was no power to the thermostat.

Called repairman and he stated I needed new thermostat wiring from the thermostat to the inside blower unit. The repair company wanted $3,000 to run a new 20 ft. thermostat wire. I felt that was excessive. I ran the new wire myself replacing the connections one at a time, color by color.

The yellow wire was connected to the "Y" terminal in the thermostat. However, the yellow wire was just terminated in the blower unit. The outside unit will not energize nor run. It does not seem correct that that wire should just be terminated in the blower unit. Help.

Comment: Your story doesn't hold water. No contractor is going to bid $3000 for a thermostat wire. There must be something else to this. Also, we'll probably need more detail about your system to help. Please revise with make and model information, at least.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the air-handler (blower unit) please?